# Adding blank space using GridBagLayout/GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am trying to add blank (clear) spacing between components. If you run my code you will see it is all connected together. I have tried using `insets` and that hasn't seemed to work. I would like to add blank space between `x1Input` and `dpLabel` to make them display as if they are not connected. Maybe I am missing something simple but it hasn't been working for me. Any advice?

My code is as follows:

```
package problemgbc;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProblemGBC extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel x1Label = new JLabel("x1:");
    JTextField x1Input = new JTextField(3);
    JLabel x2Label = new JLabel("x2:");
    JTextField x2Input = new JTextField(3);
    JLabel xLabel = new JLabel("x:");
    JTextField xInput = new JTextField(3);
    JLabel dpLabel = new JLabel("Decimal Value:");
    JComboBox decimalPlace = new JComboBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //Sets the GUI look and feel to the systems default GUI
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |
            IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    }
    ProblemGBC problemGUI = new ProblemGBC();
}

public ProblemGBC() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(650, 150);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Problem");
    ImageIcon iconImg = new ImageIcon("src/resources/icon.png");
    setIconImage(iconImg.getImage());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;

    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

    JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    top.add(xLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    top.add(xInput, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    top.add(x1Label, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    top.add(x1Input, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    top.add(x2Label, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    top.add(x2Input, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    top.add(dpLabel);
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    decimalPlace.addItem("Full Answer");
    decimalPlace.addItem("1");
    decimalPlace.addItem("2");
    decimalPlace.addItem("3");
    decimalPlace.addItem("4");
    decimalPlace.addItem("5");
    decimalPlace.addItem("6");
    decimalPlace.addItem("7");
    decimalPlace.addItem("8");
    decimalPlace.addItem("9");
    ((JLabel) decimalPlace.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    top.add(decimalPlace, gbc);
    add("North", top);

    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

}
```

Comment: You could create a label without any content and just make it a certain width and put it between the 2 elements...

Comment: Don't create a label that is a hack that is not required and will mess up the grids in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the demo code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Using the demo code you will have a better structured program that follows Swing guidelines. For example:

1. the GUI should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread,
2. you should pack() the frame before making it visible.
3. You should NOT be using: `add("North", top)`. That is don't use "magic" values and that is not the order to specify the constraint. The constraint should be specified last, like you did with the GridBagLayout.

> I have tried using insets and that hasn't seemed to work.

What make you think it is not working? 3 pixels is a small gap. Did you try a larger gap?